# How can I run Evernote on Ubuntu?

Tags: windows, android, evernote

I have *Evernote* running on Windows. I access the same on my android phone with ease.
I want to use the same Windows-run Evernote to use on my Ubuntu, so that the notes fed on Windows Evernote can be used on this.

Could anyone suggest me some solution? My knowledge of Ubuntu is almost nil.

Answer (score 38):

You can use Evernote In Ubuntu With Everpad.

> Everpad is an Evernote tool that integrates extremely well with Unity.
>   It implements a Unity Lens which automatically searches Evernote notes
>   through the Dash.<sup>1</sup>

To install,  just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the commands below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nvbn-rm/ppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install everpad
```

Otherwise, you can install [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/), which allows you to run windows applications.

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source:[Everpad](http://discussion.evernote.com/topic/31947-everpad-evernote-for-linux/)</sup>

Comment: Further reference, Everpad GitHub repo: https://github.com/nvbn/everpad

Comment: Everpad is not available for Ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: @air-dex Now it is: http://askubuntu.com/questions/362342/install-everpad-on-ubuntu-13-10

Answer (score 13):

Download the windows version of evernote, install with Wine. It runs beautifully. Fast and with no of the quirks from nevernote, nixnote and so on!

Comment: I started trying to use Everpad but ended up going this route. It is much better.

Comment: Works pretty well for me, too. Everpad doesn't show nested tags, which is pretty important for me.

Comment: I found that the latest version of Evernote didn't work (showed blank notes), so I had to downgrade to [this version](https://discussion.evernote.com/topic/86114-new-evernote-for-windows-5813-ga-update/). I figured it out using  [this forum.](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2322685)

Answer (score 3):

The Linux clone is Nevernote or NixNote. If you use that you can log into Evernote. http://nevernote.sourceforge.net/index.htm

Answer (score 2):

As said by Mitch, you can use Everpad and I personally also use it.

As an alternative, you can also use the Evernote web interface at this address: https://www.evernote.com/Home.action. This will work on all operating systemes.

Answer (score 1):

You may try **[Tusk](https://github.com/klaussinani/tusk)**.

> Tusk is an unofficial, featureful, open source, community-driven, free Evernote app used by people in more than 130 countries.
>
> ### Highlights
>
> - Black, Dark & Sepia Themes
> - Focus, Compact & Auto-Night Modes
> - Local & Global Customizable Keyboard Shortcuts
> - Export Notes as PDF, HTML & Markdown Files
> - Note Navigation
> - Yinxiang Support
> - Cross Platform
> - Scalable Interface
> - Update Notifications
> - Drag and Drop Files

(visit the [GitHub page](https://github.com/klaussinani/tusk) for more info)

Tusk is available as a snap package. So you can install it from the **Software** (store) application or by running the following command in Terminal

```
snap install tusk
```

Answer (score 1):

As of 2021 there is a [**beta** version of an **official Evernote client**](https://help.evernote.com/hc/en-us/articles/208313748) for Linux. You have to [sign up for **Early Access Program** on the Evernote homepage](https://evernote.com/earlyaccess), it is free. You may not (yet) get a link to download the app, though, [see comment from Davide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/283503/how-can-i-run-evernote-on-ubuntu/1320795?noredirect=1#comment2293082_1320795).

Earlier it was announced that it is [a deb-package](https://itsfoss.com/install-evernote-ubuntu/.). The deb-package can be installed with the Software Center, other tools or [via the command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40779/how-do-i-install-a-deb-file-via-the-command-line) as usual.

I hope there will be soon an official version without the beta-status.

Comment: To me this link about "Early Access Evernote homepage" is not working it keeps sending me to the login page, even if I'm logged in.

Comment: Thanks for the update @flibuntu. I joined the Eary Access Program 2 weeks ago.
I just got an email that informs me that I'm part of this program but there is no way I can get any link to install it.
They just say that they will let me know when some new functionalities will be released.

Comment: I will, and I hope too since I have also a Premium plan and I switched from mac to Linux 3 weeks ago.

Comment: I tried alternative clients but no one really worked. At the moment the best solution is the web client, but the experience it's quite far from the installed app client.

Comment: Hi @filbuntu, I joined the Evernote Beta testing program 6 months ago but I never received any link, it seems not existing nothing at the moment for Linux.
I'm a bit disappointed because I', paying also for the annual plan and the web version that I use in Firefox many times stuck the CPU to 100% and I have to restart my computer.

Comment: Thank you to keep this post on, I think that can be useful to others and if anybody has an update please post it here!

Answer (score 0):

Evernote is included in the [source packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=trusty&section=all&arch=any&keywords=evernote&searchon=sourcenames) `evernote-mode account-plugin-evernote`.

Can install with,

```
sudo apt-get install evernote-mode account-plugin-evernote
```

Comment: This solution is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can run `Evernote` on Ubuntu 14.04, either using PlayOnLinux or Wine directly, everything works fine. Only installing updates is a little tricky which requires removing and installing a new version of evernote.

Answer (score 0):

Evernote 5.8.13 working in Kubuntu 16.04 and Wine wine-1.9.18. Version 5.9 and 6.x didn't work.

1. Install wine:
   If your system is 64 bit, enable 32 bit architecture (if you haven't already):

   ```
   sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
   ```

   Add the repository:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:wine/wine-builds
   ```

   Update packages:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```

   Then install (example for the development branch):

   ```
   sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-devel
   ```
2. [Download and install Evernote 5.8.13](http://cdn1.evernote.com/win5/public/Evernote_5.8.13.8152.exe)