# Install Everpad on Ubuntu 13.10 and 14.04

Tags: 14.04, 13.10, evernote, everpad

I just installed a fresh copy of Ubuntu 13.10 and wanted to install Everpad but there is some issue as the PPA for it is missing it.

These were the commands which I execute (took help from http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/everpad-integrates-evernote-with-ubuntu.html and everywhere its the same):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nvbn-rm/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install everpad
```

The following which what I get when the last command is executed:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package everpad
```

Please help

Comment: I'm executing this same command on Ubuntu 14.04 and I get the same error you got. Does this mean we just have to wait till 14.04 gets updated to have this?

Comment: @strider the PPA for 14.04 might not be updated as 14.04 is yet to be released. Just wait for 1-2 days.

Comment: Thanks @MuhammadAhmadZafar. I forgot to mention, I tried it the next day and it worked.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The PPA has been updated now and you can install it on Saucy with these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nvbn-rm/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install everpad
```

Comment: Also working on trusty (14.04), may I add.

Comment: Not working for me on 16.04.

Answer (score 3):

The ppa is not available for the Saucy version, only raring. In normal occasions, you can change in your /etc/sources.list.d/ the distribution to a previous one, like raring, but in this particular case, that is not working, as you can see here: https://github.com/nvbn/everpad/issues/369

So, the only option for now seems to compile the application from the source code.

Sorry!

Comment: I tried making git clone of it and running the command `python setup.py install` but that also didn't work

Comment: The everpad ppa now includes 13.10 in case anyone was wondering