# Run Everpad on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, everpad

I have installed Everpad in 32bit Ubuntu machine. When I run it I have error:

```
root@1025C:~# everpad
"sni-qt/10220" WARN  22:57:49.764 void StatusNotifierItemFactory::connectToSnw() Invalid interface to SNW_SERVICE 
ERROR:dbus.proxies:Introspect error on :1.2:/EverpadProvider: dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: How did you install it? And can you try NOT launching it as root.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please, could you put some of your time to read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: It seems [everpad has been discontinued](http://alternativeto.net/software/everpad/). Some options: [nixnote](https://github.com/baumgarr/nixnote2), evernote by wine, or evernote interface web/browser plugin. More options on [alternativeTo site](http://alternativeto.net/software/everpad/)

Answer (score 0):

I installed `everpad` using this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/368967/32239) on 14.04.

If run using sudo I also get the same error:

```
$ sudo everpad
"sni-qt/27637" WARN  22:25:20.906 void StatusNotifierItemFactory::connectToSnw() Invalid interface to SNW_SERVICE
```

You need to run `everpad` as a normal user, not root:

```
$ everpad
```

You get the dbus error because when invoked as a different user you're loosing the `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS`.

It's not permitted because the bus daemon disconnects if it detects a connection from a different user.

Sources:

- [Access another user's D-Bus session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6496847/access-another-users-d-bus-session)
- [How to interact with existing dbus session through sudo?](http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/dbus/2014-March/016160.html)